# How do I turn on nanosecond precision when capturing live traffic?

Tags: c, linux, pcap, libpcap, packet-capture

**How do I tell libpcap v1.6.2 to store nanosecond values in `struct pcap_pkthdr::ts.tv_usec` (instead of microsecond values) when capturing live packets?**

<sup>(Note:  This question is similar to [How to enable nanosecond resolution when capturing live packets in libpcap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502139/how-to-enable-nanosecond-resolution-when-capturing-live-packets-in-libpcap) but that question is vague enough that I decided to ask a new question.)</sup>

For offline and "dead" captures, the following functions can be used to tell libpcap to fill the `struct pcap_pkthdr`'s `ts.tv_usec` member with nanosecond values:

- [`pcap_open_dead_with_tstamp_precision()`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_dead.3pcap.html)
- [`pcap_open_offline_with_tstamp_precision()`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_offline.3pcap.html)
- [`pcap_fopen_offline_with_tstamp_precision()`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_offline.3pcap.html)

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be `_with_tstamp_precision` variants for [`pcap_open_live()`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_live.3pcap.html) or [`pcap_create()`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_create.3pcap.html).

I believe that capturing live packets with nanosecond resolution should be possible, because the [changelog](http://www.tcpdump.org/libpcap-changes.txt) for v1.5.0 says (emphasis mine):

> Add support for getting nanosecond-resolution time stamps **when capturing** and reading capture files

I did see the [`pcap_set_tstamp_type()`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_set_tstamp_type.3pcap.html) function and the [`pcap-tstamp` man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-tstamp.7.html), which says:

> - `PCAP_TSTAMP_HOST`—`host`:  Time stamp provided by the host on which the capture is being done.  The precision of this time stamp is unspecified; it might or might not be synchronized with the host operating system's clock.
> - `PCAP_TSTAMP_HOST_LOWPREC`—`host_lowprec`:  Time stamp provided by the host on which the capture is being done.  This is a low-precision time stamp, synchronized with the host operating system's clock.
> - `PCAP_TSTAMP_HOST_HIPREC`—`host_hiprec`:  Time stamp provided by the host on which the capture is being done.  This is a high-precision time stamp; it might or might not be synchronized with the host operating system's clock.  It might be more expensive to fetch than `PCAP_TSTAMP_HOST_LOWPREC`.
> - `PCAP_TSTAMP_ADAPTER`—`adapter`:  Time stamp provided by the network adapter on which the capture is being done.  This is a high-precision time stamp, synchronized with the host operating system's clock.
> - `PCAP_TSTAMP_ADAPTER_UNSYNCED`—`adapter_unsynced`:  Time stamp provided by the network adapter on which the capture is being done.  This is a high-precision time stamp; it is not synchronized with the host operating system's clock.

Does the phrase "high-precision time stamp" here mean that nanosecond values are stored in the header's `ts.tv_usec` field?  If so, `PCAP_TSTAMP_HOST` says "unspecified", so how do I determine at runtime whether the `ts.tv_usec` field holds microseconds or nanoseconds?  And which of these is the default if `pcap_set_tstamp_type()` is never called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pcap_create()` does little if anything to set parameters for the capture device, and has no alternative calls for setting those parameters; this is by design.  The intent, at the time `pcap_create()` and `pcap_activate()` were introduced, was that neither of those calls would have to be changed in order to support new parameters, and that new APIs would be introduced as new parameters are introduced.

You're supposed to call `pcap_create()` to create a not-yet-activated handle, set the parameters with the appropriate calls, and then attempt to activate the handle with `pcap_activate()`.

One of the appropriate calls is `pcap_set_tstamp_precision()`, which is the call you use between `pcap_create()` and `pcap_activate()` to specify that you want nanosecond-precision time stamps.  The default is microsecond-precision time stamps, for backwards source and binary compatibility.

Note that `pcap_set_tstamp_precision()` will fail if you can't get nanosecond-precision time stamps from the device on which you're capturing, so you must check whether it succeeds or fails or call `pcap_get_tstamp_precision()` after activating the `pcap_t` in order to see what time stamp precision you'll be getting.

And, no, "high-precision" has nothing to do with whether you get microseconds or nanoseconds, it has to do with whether the nominal microseconds or nanoseconds value really provide microsecond or nanosecond granularity or whether you'll always get values that are multiples of a power of 10 because the clock being used doesn't measure down to the microsecond or nanosecond.

Comment: Can't I just check the return value of `pcap_set_tstamp_precision()` to see if it failed instead of calling `pcap_get_tstamp_precision()`?

Comment: I've updated both man pages to mention the functions.  The updates will show up in some future release; when that'll show up in Your Favorite Distribution/*BSD/OS X/Solaris/etc. is another matter.